# React-Native android ndk 13b support?

Tags: android, facebook, android-ndk, react-native

Trying to use native app built using NDK 13b with React Native and getting issues due to libgnustl-shared.so lib. Trying to understand why React Native does not support using 13b or to any latest available NDK. It is still using very old (May 2015) NDK to build react-native?

Comment: What are the *issues* with **libgnustl_shared.so** ? Note that React Native is built with NDK r10, and you can use it as is, why do you want to rebuild it from sources?

Comment: The native app is build with libgnustl from 13b toolchain and ReactNative is with older version. Due to this I might need to rebuild reactnative with 13b or need to use old NDK for native app to resolve...

Comment: As long as the native parts does not interact directly with ReactNative, you are under no obligation to rebuild the latter.

Comment: My imported app contains both app lib and libgnustl_shared.so which will be a conflict the final app contains two different versions of libgnustl where both are required. I am able to resolve this by recompiling my app with static libgnustl instead shared. Which increated the final app size considerably. What I am trying to understand here is about the reason why react-native is still using NDK r10 which was around 3 years old and what is the plan to use latest NDK for react native.

Comment: Have you tried to simply replace libgnustl_shared.so with the 13b version?

Comment: Yes @AlexCohn but that did not work. Anyway to get back to my question I am just trying to understand the need to stick with old NDK or whats plan for release with new NDK.

Comment: Facebook devs don't monitor this site. You will be better served if you open a new ticket at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues